# Function not plotted between 0 and 1

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I am trying to plot the function x^0.5 / ( x^0.5 + 10^0.5 ), the plot will only start at x=1 but not at x=0. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=1
  ] 
    \addplot[mark=no,black,very thick,domain=0:20]{x^0.5/(x^0.5+10^0.5)};
    \addlegendentry{}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: No plot between x=0 and x=1]

### Modification

If I use the same code but plot only the function x/(x+10) everything works fine.

I tried to play around a bit with the domain property and if I set it for example to 0.0001 the plot starts in the origin. However, the function has a messed up shape between x=0 and x=1.

```
\addplot[mark=no,black,very thick,domain=0.0001:20]{x^0.5/(x^0.5+10^0.5)};
```

[image: Bad fix with domain parameter]

### Question

> How do I get the function properly plotted in the range x=0 and x=1?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Try `smooth` key to the addplot[option].